# Symfony 5+ nested form collection rendering

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

```
{% form_theme form _self %}
{% block collection_entry_row %}

    {% set fields = form.attributes.children[0].children %}
    {% for key, field in fields %}
        {{ form_widget(field) }}
        {{ form_widget(fields[key]) }}
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

And I get this error:

```
Neither the property "attributes" nor one of the methods "attributes()", "getattributes()"/"isattributes()"/"hasattributes()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView".
```

But this

```
{% set fields = form.attributes.children[0] %}
{% for key, field in fields %}
    {{ dump(field) }}
{% endfor %}
```

---

Produces this:

```
Symfony\Component\Form\FormView {#2150 ▼
  +vars: array:33 [▶]
  +parent: Symfony\Component\Form\FormView {#2203 ▶}
  +children: []
  -rendered: false
  -methodRendered: false
}
```

And yet inside the `form_start()` I can do the following and render one field at a time:

```
{% set tempInput = form.children['attributes'].children[0].children['attributes'].children[0].children['pin'] %}
{{ form_widget(tempInput) }}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: How did you try to render your field `child` ?

Comment: Using `form_widget()`

Comment: Did you try ?
`{% for child in children %} {{ form_row(child) }} {% endfor %}`

Comment: I believe I did try each, row, widget, etc...what difference would it make tho? On a normal form you can choose whether to render whole field, just the control, label, etc, no??

Comment: When in `collection_row`, `form.attributes` becomes `form`, since it's the form that you are currently rendering, so iterating over `form.children` should work. Is there another nested field with the name `attributes` that doesn't have a `type` key?

Comment: There is, yes. I managed to render fields individually by starting from the root element and working out. See OP for an update.

Answer (score 1):

just had the same questions as you about this subject, and since i didn't understands the way to use the "{% block collection_row %}" i've found this following workaround.

I find out that the problem i had was coming from the 2 last item of the form.children: "submit" and "_token".
Because, of course, they will not have the variable name you are searching in the other "real" forms childs.

So i just added a check to the length of the children array to exclude this "submit" and "_token" items.
(The test might certainly be different for your case).

```
{% for child in form.children %}
  {% if not child.children | length != 4  %} // my array has 4 items, submit and _token have none

    {{ form_widget(child.children.variableName) }}

  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

As you can see you can access your collection variable between the if like this:

```
{{ form_widget(child.children.variableName) }}
```

Peace.